# Can converting macros to .exe, bypass Outlook blocking macros on my work computer?

Tags: vba, outlook, executable

I have a macro which is used for a personal inbox in Outlook.

I used the macro once at work through the VB editor. The second time I tried to run it (using the F8 key), Outlook blocked the macro from been implemented.

My organization has disabled the macro settings options in the Trust Center due to which I cannot change the security settings.

Can I convert these macros to .exe files to bypass this security of Outlook? Will any change have to be made to the code of the macros so it will work in .exe format?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert to VB6. VB.Net will probably be more challenging.

You might also want to think about converting to a COM add0-in instead of a standalone exe. http://www.outlookcode.com/ is a good place to start.